# Microcanonical ensemble: imanation for $N$ particles

Tags: homework-and-exercises, statistical-mechanics

> **Q:** Consider an isolated system of $N$ non-interacting spins or magnetic dipoles with magnetic moment $\vec{\mu}=\mu_{z}\hat{z}$ and spin S=$1$, so we have $m_{z}=(-1,0,1)\hat{z}$, in a magnetic field $\vec{B}=B_{z}\hat{z}$. 
>   Considering that the numbers of particles with $m_{z}=0$ is equal to $0$, calculate the imanation/magnetization $M$.

**Issue #1:** I'm quite confused about that questions because I don't understand **which total energy should I consider constant in my macrostate** in order to count the compatible microstates.

**Edit:** New steps using the help given in the answers:
So, as gatsu says, I can consider my total energy as $$E=\mu_{0}B(-2N_{+}+N),$$ but my question now is, **why can this be considered as a constant condition for the macrostate?** It depends of the microstate condition 'number of particles with the spin $+1$' $N_{+}$, isn't it?

Comment: I have tried to address your latest question. But the point is that indeed fixing $E$, with imposed $N_0 = 0$ is uniquely describable by the value of the macro variable $N_+$. All the statistical thermodynamics of your system will be provided by the quantity $\Omega(N_+,N)$ with which you can derive the relation between the temperature and the energy for instance. Note that in this constrained micro canonical ensemble (with $N_0 = 0$), $N_+$ does not fluctuate; it is as fixed as $E$ is.

Comment: Ahá! $N_{+}$ macro variable? I don't get it. But, ok, let's consider it as a macro variable, so $$\Omega(N_{+},N)=\frac{N!}{N_{+}!(N-N_{+})!}$$ for a fixed $E=\mu_{0}B(-2N_{+}+N)$, how can I compute now the imanation? Like that: $$M=\mu_{0}\sum_{1}^{N}P_{i}s_{i},$$ with $$P_{i}=\frac{1}{\Omega(N_{+},N)}?$$

Comment: If $E, N$ and $N_0$ are fixed then $M = -E/B$...as far as I can see. Maybe I am missing something but I think this should be the answer.

Comment: Mm and if I'm asked to find the imanation value compatible with the greater number of microstates? Well, I'll ask for more information, I don't see why $N_{+}$ should be considered a macro variable anyway. Thank you very much.

Comment: Ah. That's a different question then. And I think it does not make sense in a true micro canonical ensemble. Anyway, in that case, you take you $\Omega(N_+,N)$ and you just have to maximise with respect to $N_+$. You will find $N/2$.

Answer (score 1):

The total magnetic energy of the system is fixed.

This would read

(1)  $E = \sum_{i=1}^N -\vec{\mu}_i \cdot \vec{B} = B\mu_0(-N_+ + N_-) $

with the general constraint

(2) $N_+ + N_- + N_0 = N$.

Where $N_{\pm}$ is the number of spins with projection $m_s = \pm 1$, $N_0$ the number of spins with $m_s = 0$ and $\mu_0$ the magnitude of the magnetic dipole.

To simplify your life you are told that $N_0 = 0$ so that the second equation reads:

(2) $N_+ + N_- = N$

The problem becomes now quite classical as it mostly reduces to a set of half spins problem.

EDIT:

Because the ensemble is not only fixed $(E,N)$ but in fact fixed $(E,N,N_0)$ it means that fixing $E$ is equivalent to fixing $N_+$. The total number of micro states in this system will thus be $\Omega(E,N,N_0=0) = \Omega(N_+,N)$.

Comment: This was helpful, thank you. But I have some questions (I preferred to edit the question so I can use the Latex environment).